# Keyboard Issue with Synergy, Oracle Virtual Box & Linux Hosts

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard, synergy

I'm getting weird behavior using synergy with Oracle Virtual Box VM over Linux Ubuntu systems.

My setup has

- A Ubuntu Linux 11.04 (synergy server) with US International keyboard layout (workstation)
- A Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (synergy client) with Brazilian Portuguese ABNT keyboard layout (laptop)
- A Oracle Virtual Box VM with Windows 7 (no synergy) with Brazilian Portuguese ABNT keyboard layout running over ubuntu on the laptop.

Working with Ubuntu on the laptop using workstation keyboard is fine, no problems here.

Also, using Windows from laptop keyboard works perfectly. However, using Windows with the workstation keyboard has some weird behaviors. Most of the keys are fine, but I get weird behavior regarding control keys (shift, control, caps, etc). For instance, when pressing shift or caps I start "gEttING sENtenCeS LiKe THis", and only stops after I press shift a couple times. 
Also, some of the keys don't seem to have mapping (for instance, < and >). Any thoughts on how can I approach this problem?

Comment: I have been having similar issues with keyboard control keys. e.g. ctrl-c will sometimes put my system into shutdown. Since synergy is a recent install I was wondering if it could be related.